# Does vue emit an event even if there is no listener?

Tags: vuejs3

I am looking to emit a lot of data from an event in some shared Vue3 code.

I only have an event listener for this emit on certain circumstances.

Will Vue always emit this data if I use the `emit('myEvent', lotsOfData)` syntax or does it know to see if there is an active listener?

Comment: By design, events do not check for listeners. What is the problem you're trying to solve by not emitting when there's no listener?

Comment: It sends a lot of data, so I'd prefer not to emit unless someone is listening. I can send in a property to indicate whether I'd like to listen, but ideally I wouldn't need to do this.

Comment: That's a non-issue. The emitter (and emitting an event, in general) does not consume additional resources. The data is already in memory. On the other hand, a mechanism for tracking active listeners would consume both memory and processing power. In other words, the mechanism you're requesting would create the very problem you believe it would solve.

Comment: Feel free to put this as an answer and I will accept it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, a defined emit is always triggered, even if the current parent is not listening.

By design, [Event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event)s do not check for active listeners before emitting (under the hood, Vue uses [CustomEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomEvent) for component emits; most notably, these events do not bubble; they can only be listened to by the emitter's immediate parent) ***<sup>1</sup>***.

Regardless of the amount of data emitted, emitting an event does not use additional resources (as the data is already in memory when the event is emitted).

A mechanism for tracking active event listeners would actually consume both memory and processing power ***<sup>2</sup>***. It would thus create the very problem you are trying to solve, which is a non-issue.

---

***<sup>1</sup>*** - only applies to non-native events. Native events (e.g: `click`, `input`, `change`, etc ) are not CustomEvents and bubble as expected.

***<sup>2</sup>*** - although anything is greater than nothing, a scenario where this resource consumption would amount to a significant performance issue is hard to imagine and extremely unlikely